# Pandas: find the column name of max value, I need filter columns with star text?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this,

[image]

so I store the percentage of each rating (stars) into pandas like this

[image]

Now I want to get the column name of the largest value, for example

```
1_star  2_star  3_star  4_star  5_star
0.023   0.112   0.474   0.316   0.075

## returns 3_star
```

How can I do it?

I find an anwer perfectly fit my situation, [Pandas second largest value's column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015489/pandas-second-largest-values-column-name), but it seems too complex. After all, I can get the max value by `df.max()`, why getting the column name of the max value is so complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select row to `Series`:

```
print (df)
   1_star  2_star  3_star  4_star  5_star
0   0.023   0.112   0.474   0.316   0.075

print (df.iloc[0].idxmax())
3_star
```

If need values for all `DataFrame` use [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) - output is `Series`:

```
print (df.idxmax(axis=1))
```

Also you can `filter` only columns with `_star` text by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
print (df.filter(like='_star').idxmax(axis=1))
```

Comment: That's the magic, I didn't searched out this function, thanks alot!